# Time complexity of accessing an element in a tuple

Tags: python, complexity-theory, tuples

There is similar question about hash (dictionaries) and lists, also there is a good piece of info here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

But I didn't find anything about tuples.

The access time for

```
data_structure[i]
```

- for a linked list is in general O(n)
- for dictionary is ~ O(1)

What about tuple?
Is it O(n) like for a linked list or O(1) like for an array?

Comment: `for list is O(n) in general` Wrong. Unless you're talking about linked lists, which don't exist anywhere in Python's standard library. What Python calls "list" is a dynamic **array** and hence has O(1) item access. (By the way, the page you link says exactly that.)

Comment: The time complexity to get an item in a list is O(1), I'd assume it's the same for a tuple.

Answer (score 11):

It's O(1) for both list and tuple. They are both morally equivalent to an integer indexed array.

Comment: @tkerwin I mean that in the context of this question, for all intents and purposes, you are safe to regard lists and tuples as integer indexed arrays.

Comment: Curiosity, is morally equivalent often used to mean that in the UK?

Comment: @marr75 I use it quite often here in the UK ;-) Do a websearch for "moral equivalent" and add in some programming terms, e.g. goto, return, exception and you'll see that I am not alone.

Comment: I get it with "goto" because there are debates about the "evilness" of goto, so perhaps that's its root? Seems most applicable to debates about crufty code or language features that subtract from usability but I'll keep in mind that the use is growing. Thanks.

Comment: how about for checking if an element exists in a tuple? 3 in (1,2,3). Is this also O(1), or O(N) like a list?

Comment: @BigDreamz O(n)

Answer (score 4):

Lists and tuples are indexable in the exact same way arrays are in other languages.

A simplified explanation is that space is allocated for references to objects, those references take up a uniform amount of space, and any index is simply multiplied by the size of the reference to get an offset into the array. This gives constant, O(1), access for lists and tuples.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but here I have question about insert into list: Since its like an array, doest it mean that insert is not O(1) ? Also can you give a link here with info about Time Complexity of python data structures?

Comment: Your question did not mention inserts and in fact you seemed to be clear on the timings for a list. You yourself have already given a link with what I would call the most definitive info on time complexity of python data structures.

Answer (score 3):

Getting an item from a linked-list is O(n), but Python lists have array-based implementations so the cost is O(1).

Tuples are also implemented using arrays so it's O(1) for them too.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `O(1)`, because it really is only a list.

But for python lists, I'd expect `O(1)` too! You might want to think about it again...

Comment: A tuple isn't a list. It's a sequence, but that's all.