# Search for files that match any strings from a list?

Tags: python, match

I want to recursively walk through a directory, find the files that match *any* of the strings in a given list, and then copy these files to another folder. I thought the any() function would accomplish this, but I get a TypeError that it expected a string, not a list. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
string_to_match = ['apple.txt', 'pear.txt', 'banana.txt']

for root, subdirs, filename in os.walk(source_dir)
    if any(s in filename for s in string_to_match):
        shutil.copy(filename, destination_dir)
        print(filename)
```

I know glob.glob can work well for finding files that match a specific string or pattern, but I haven't been able to find an answer that allows for multiple matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `in`

Example:

```
string_to_match = ['apple.txt', 'pear.txt', 'banana.txt']

for root, subdirs, filename in os.walk(source_dir)
    if filename in string_to_match:
        shutil.copy(filename, destination_dir)
        print(filename)
```

Here also a glob version:

```
import glob
import itertools

root_dir = '/home/user'
files = ['apple.txt', 'pear.txt', 'banana.txt']
files_found = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([glob.glob(f'{root_dir}/**/{f}', recursive=True) for f in files])
for f in files_found:
     shutil.copy(f, destination_dir)
```

Comment: This works really well, thank you for showing both versions!

Answer (score 1):

First, find an element in list takes O(n), so just convert it to a set which takes O(1).

Then you can do like this

```
string_to_match = {'apple.txt', 'pear.txt', 'banana.txt'}
for filename in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if filename in string_to_match:
        shutil.copy(filename, destination_dir)
        print(filename)
```

Comment: Finding an element in a Python list seems to be `O(1)` instead of `O(n)` https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153348/time-complexity-of-accessing-an-element-in-a-tuple

Comment: dang good answer :) pretty close to mine (+1)

Comment: @albert `Get Item` means `a_list[4]` not `test in a_list` or `a_list.index('test')` (see `x in a` O(n))

Comment: Unfortunately this returns the error: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 0):

I would use sets

```
def find_names(names,source_dir):
    names = set(names)
    # note os.walk will walk the subfolders too
    # if you just want that source_dir use `strings_to_match.intersection(os.listdir(sourcedir))`
    for root,subdirs,fnames in os.walk(sourcedir):
       for matched_name in strings_to_match.intersection(fnames):
           yield os.path.join(root,matched_name)
    
strings_to_match = ['apple.txt', 'pear.txt', 'banana.txt']
for match in find_names(strings_to_match,'/path/to/start'):
   print("Match:", match)
```

[edited] typo `intersection` not `intersect`

(you could alternatively just pass in a set `{'a','b','c'}` instead of a list `['a','b','c']` and skip the conversion to a set)

here is an alternative that only  looks in the source dir (not children)

```
def find_names_in_folder(names,source_dir):
    return [os.path.join(source_dir,n) for n in set(names).intersection(os.listdir(source_dir))]
```